# Big numbers not recognised as integers by bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line

So I am trying to write a script that prints the sum of every digit in a number, to the power of another number.

So for example, if the input is: `script 123 2` than the script calculates `1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2` and outputs `14`.

My script:

```
Num=$1
s=0
while [ $Num -gt 0 ]
do
   k=$(( $Num % 10 ))

   Num=$(( $Num / 10 ))

   s=$(( $s + ($k**$2)))
done
echo $s
```

This works for smaller numbers, but numbers like "3706907995955475988644381" cause the following error: `line 5: [: 3706907995955475988644381: integer expression expected`

How can I make this script work with big numbers?

Comment: bash can only handle 64-bit integers. If you need arbitrarily large numbers, you have to choose a different tool.

Comment: Try using `bc` to do the calculation: `echo '3706907995955475988644381 ^ 2' | bc`

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the input as a string, calculate its length and use substring parameter expansion to extract single digits.

```
Num=$1
Exp=$2
s=0
# string length
i=${#Num}
while [ $i -gt 0 ]
do
   # index is 0-based, decrement before using
   : $((i--))
   # 1 character at index i
   k=${Num:$i:1}

   s=$(( $s + ($k**$Exp)))
done
echo $s
```

**Note:** The code lacks error handling. You might get unexpected results if the input contains non-digit characters, and the calculation might overflow for *very* long numbers.